# Set trim_length of field through UI for blog entries

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I am using the Blog module, but don't like the 600 character trim length.  I want 2000 char.

But, I can't find out where to change this in the admin console.

I was able to update the trim length through the mysql console, but this seems less than ideal.

The code below was how I was able to complete the config change.  How can i do this without a SQL update?

```
mysql> select * from field_config_instance where id=9\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 9
   field_id: 2
 field_name: body
entity_type: node
     bundle: blog
       data: a:6:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Body";s:6:"widget";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:26:"text_textarea_with_summary";s:8:"settings";a:2:{s:4:"rows";i:20;s:12:"summary_rows";i:5;}s:6:"weight";i:31;s:6:"module";s:4:"text";}s:8:"settings";a:3:{s:15:"display_summary";b:1;s:15:"text_processing";i:1;s:18:"user_register_form";b:0;}s:7:"display";a:2:{s:7:"default";a:5:{s:5:"label";s:6:"hidden";s:4:"type";s:12:"text_default";s:8:"settings";a:0:{}s:6:"module";s:4:"text";s:6:"weight";i:0;}s:6:"teaser";a:5:{s:5:"label";s:6:"hidden";s:4:"type";s:23:"text_summary_or_trimmed";s:8:"settings";a:1:{s:11:"trim_length";i:600;}s:6:"module";s:4:"text";s:6:"weight";i:0;}}s:8:"required";b:0;s:11:"description";s:0:"";}
    deleted: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update field_config_instance set data='a:6:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Body";s:6:"widget";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:26:"text_textarea_with_summary";s:8:"settings";a:2:{s:4:"rows";i:20;s:12:"summary_rows";i:5;}s:6:"weight";i:31;s:6:"module";s:4:"text";}s:8:"settings";a:3:{s:15:"display_summary";b:1;s:15:"text_processing";i:1;s:18:"user_register_form";b:0;}s:7:"display";a:2:{s:7:"default";a:5:{s:5:"label";s:6:"hidden";s:4:"type";s:12:"text_default";s:8:"settings";a:0:{}s:6:"module";s:4:"text";s:6:"weight";i:0;}s:6:"teaser";a:5:{s:5:"label";s:6:"hidden";s:4:"type";s:23:"text_summary_or_trimmed";s:8:"settings";a:1:{s:11:"trim_length";i:3000;}s:6:"module";s:4:"text";s:6:"weight";i:0;}}s:8:"required";b:0;s:11:"description";s:0:"";}'
    -> where id=9;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`
```

Comment: First try to set up your blog teasers like @Triskelion suggested below, and if it doesn't fit your need, then you can try Smart [Smart Trim module](https://drupal.org/project/smart_trim) which  improves the "Summary or Trimmed" formatter built into Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to `admin/structure/types/manage/blog/display/teaser` and on the right next to the format settings for *Summary or trimmed* you will see a button with a little star on it. Click on it and set your trim length.

Comment: Ok.... seems to work.  Thanks! 

But how come there's no blog content type at `admin/structure/types/manage/`?  Manually constructing a url seems odd.

Comment: The content type should be there. If not you have a different issue.

Comment: Odd.  The blog content trim length is definitely working as expected, but there must be something odd that would prevent it from showing on the content types page.